# How to connect network switch with ADSL broadband?

Tags: switch, broadband

I have a ADSL broadband and I have connected two computers to that wired broadband using a network switch . But when I connect one computer to the internet and try to connect the other one , it does not get connected and when I connect the second computer first and then try to connect the first , again it does not get connected . How can I solve this problem and use internet on both the computers at same time ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is quite simple: Use a router.

Since one PC can connect, you already have a modem. Simply buy any router, optionally with WiFi, and you’re good to go.

Answer (score 0):

First Scenario:

Adsl Modem(No Routing):
Buy a Home/Office Router and set your PPPoE conection to from there.

Second Scenario:

Adsl Modem with Router Features and MiniSwitch(4 or more ports)
Just be sure to connect from ADSL modem with PPPoE Feature from there and do not use PPPoE setting from your hosts.